# ASP.NET Post back a Web-control using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-controls

I have a embedded **Web-Control** in a Master Page when user clicks a HTML link i wants to **post back** this **web control** using JavaScript is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a javascript function available: `__doPostBack`.
You can register it from your web control by using the [GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx) API.

Here's [a sample](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2005/11/04/59081.aspx) and the [MSDN how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720099%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LinkButton control, that will generate JavaScript to cause a page postback and then you can do whatever logic is necessary in the Master Page (or derivatives) code behind.